# Testing focus in Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I'm wondering if there is any way to test for where focus is set on a page, using Laravel Dusk. I have a form whose first element should always receive focus when the page loads. I don't see anything obvious in the Dusk documentation for this. I'm using Laravel 5.5.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$element = $browser->element($selector);
$this->assertTrue($browser->driver->switchTo()->activeElement()->equals($element));
```

**UPDATE**: In Dusk 3.0.8 you can use `assertFocused()` and `assertNotFocused()`.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like assertTrue is not a valid assertion, at least in 5.5. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/dusk#available-assertions

Comment: `assertTrue()` is part of PHPUnit, not of Dusk. Did you try it?

Comment: I see- the documentation is really underwhelming for Dusk. As someone who is new to automated testing, I'm not seeing any clear information on how Dusk works, and how I can utilize native PHPUnit methods with it. I have a slightly modified version of your code that runs, but is failing. So I'll keep poking at it until I can get it working. It may also have to do with the fact that I'm using Vue.js to set focus.

Comment: That's always vulnerable to timing problems. Try something like `sleep(1);` before testing the focus.

Comment: In Dusk 3.0.8 you can use assertFocused() and assertNotFocused().